# JNI issue for ffmpeg

Tags: android

Android is not allowing me to place the large video on surface, it's Android - firmware(Video view) limitation, so resolving this issue  need codec interface for place video on surface.

i am trying to integrate codec using  JAVA JNI.

i am using ffmpeg library for video codec interface, that works  but facing some issues. Audio is running but video not appear on surface view.

C++ video view library is not getting two values  sws_format_name(c->srcFormat), sws_format_name(c->dstFormat) so error.

error msg occur:08-23 18:12:29.002: ERROR/FFMpegMediaPlayer(3889): AV_LOG_WARNING: No accelerated colorspace conversion found from %s to %s.

NOTE:Here unavailability of c->dstFormat this value it's not going switch statement for accelerate the video.For more information review the attached document.

Error Block resign:

if (t)
        return t;

```
av_log(c, AV_LOG_WARNING, "No accelerated colorspace conversion found from %s to %s.\n", sws_format_name(c->srcFormat), sws_format_name(c->dstFormat))
```

;

```
switch (c->dstFormat) {
case PIX_FMT_RGB48BE:
case PIX_FMT_RGB48LE:    return yuv2rgb_c_48;
case PIX_FMT_ARGB:
case PIX_FMT_ABGR:       if (CONFIG_SWSCALE_ALPHA && c->srcFormat == PIX_FMT_YUVA420P) return yuva2argb_c;
case PIX_FMT_RGBA:
case PIX_FMT_BGRA:       return (CONFIG_SWSCALE_ALPHA && c->srcFormat == PIX_FMT_YUVA420P) ? yuva2rgba_c : yuv2rgb_c_32;
case PIX_FMT_RGB24:      return yuv2rgb_c_24_rgb;
case PIX_FMT_BGR24:      return yuv2rgb_c_24_bgr;
case PIX_FMT_RGB565:
case PIX_FMT_BGR565:
case PIX_FMT_RGB555:
case PIX_FMT_BGR555:     return yuv2rgb_c_16;
case PIX_FMT_RGB444:
case PIX_FMT_BGR444:     return yuv2rgb_c_12_ordered_dither;
case PIX_FMT_RGB8:
case PIX_FMT_BGR8:       return yuv2rgb_c_8_ordered_dither;
case PIX_FMT_RGB4:
case PIX_FMT_BGR4:       return yuv2rgb_c_4_ordered_dither;
case PIX_FMT_RGB4_BYTE:
case PIX_FMT_BGR4_BYTE:  return yuv2rgb_c_4b_ordered_dither;
case PIX_FMT_MONOBLACK:  return yuv2rgb_c_1_ordered_dither;
default:
    assert(0);
```

Please help me , i will very thankful of you.

please confirm me error resign.